# certmanager implementation in the fabric8

Tags: fabric8

I read an article https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/07/16/whats-new-fabric8-kubernetes-client-version-550#new_features_in_fabric8_kubernetes_client_5_5_0, it mentioned in 5.5 release it adds "Certification management", however, seem I could not find any source codes related to it in fabric8 repo.

when I run a simple code like this

```
        try (CertManagerClient certManagerClient = new DefaultCertManagerClient()) {

 
            CertificateRequest certificateRequest = new CertificateRequestBuilder()
                .withNewMetadata().withName("barry_coding_test").endMetadata()
                .withNewSpec()
                .withRequest(request)
                .withIsCA(false)
                .addToUsages("signing", "digital signature", "server auth")
                .withDuration(Duration.parse("2160h"))
                .withIssuerRef(new ObjectReferenceBuilder()
                    .withName("barry-dlc-cert-issuer")
                    .withKind("Issuer")
                    .withGroup("cert-manager.io")
                    .build())
                .endSpec()
                .build();

            certManagerClient.v1().certificateRequests().inNamespace("barry").create(certificateRequest);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It throws error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/dsl/base/HasMetadataOperation.<init>(Lio/fabric8/kubernetes/client/dsl/base/OperationContext;)V (loaded from file:/Users/zhBarry@ca.ibm.com/osprey/mvnexample/java-app/dlc-management-service/libs/kubernetes-client-5.8.0.jar by jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@40575da4) called from class io.fabric8.certmanager.client.api.v1.internal.CertificateRequestOperationsImpl (loaded from file:/Users/zhBarry@ca.ibm.com/osprey/mvnexample/java-app/dlc-management-service/libs/certmanager-client-5.5.0.jar by jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@40575da4).
    at io.fabric8.certmanager.client.api.v1.internal.CertificateRequestOperationsImpl.<init>(CertificateRequestOperationsImpl.java:32)
    at io.fabric8.certmanager.client.api.v1.internal.CertificateRequestOperationsImpl.<init>(CertificateRequestOperationsImpl.java:28)
    at io.fabric8.certmanager.client.V1APIGroupClient.certificateRequests(V1APIGroupClient.java:51)
    at com.ibm.si.osprey.App.main(App.java:67)
```

I could not find source code CertificateRequestOperationsImpl.java at all in the repo.

Any ideas for it? Where can I certmanager implementation in the fabric8 repo?

Comment: Have you added `certmanager-client` as a dependency in your project: https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.fabric8/certmanager-client/5.9.0/bundle ?

Comment: https://javadoc.io/doc/io.fabric8/kubernetes-model-certificates/latest/index.html, no any CertificateRequest stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't find CertManager related features in `kubernetes-client` jar itself. All Fabric8 Kubernetes Client Extensions are available via their own individual jars. For CertManager, you need to add this dependency:

Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
  <artifactId>certmanager-client</artifactId>
  <version>5.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
implementation 'io.fabric8:certmanager-client:5.9.0'
```

There is an example placed in https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/tree/master/extensions/certmanager/examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/certmanager/examples/v1 . Maybe this section needs improvement; you're welcome to contribute some more examples if you have some time :-) .

I've tested your sample on a demo project with `certmanager-client` dependency with certmanager installed on minikube. You can find demo project here: https://github.com/rohankanojia-forks/cert-manager-java-extension-demo

Comment: Hello Rohan, the above code works for me. Now I want to fetch a CertificateRequest with instance name, you know, there is no java.doc to introduce it, I search javadoc.io/doc/io.fabric8/kubernetes-model-certificates/latest/…, I could not find reference for CertificateRequest. Do you know how to get a CertificateRequest and delete a CertificateRequest? Because I could not find any method/interface documents, so I don't know how to get a CertificateRequest, how to list CertificateRequest and how to watch CertificateRequest? Could you help add them to your demo repo? Thanks

Comment: I've added examples for CertificateReqeust [Get](https://github.com/rohankanojia-forks/cert-manager-java-extension-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/io/fabric8/demo/CertificateRequestGet.java), [List](https://github.com/rohankanojia-forks/cert-manager-java-extension-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/io/fabric8/demo/CertificateRequestListExample.java) and [Watch](https://github.com/rohankanojia-forks/cert-manager-java-extension-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/io/fabric8/demo/CertificateRequestWatchExample.java) . Please review them whenever you get time.